# UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct logistics.Vehicle memory[] memory to storage not yet supported

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays, struct

I'm encountering an issue while working on a smart contract. I have three structs that are interdependent: Participant, Vehicle, and Sensor. Participant contains an array of Vehicle structs, and each Vehicle struct contains an array of Sensor structs. Finally, I map Participant to a string in the mapping used below.

However, I'm unable to implement this. In the function `addParticipants`, I've attempted two methods (the second one is commented out). Additionally, I tried adding the struct without the dynamic array by simply passing `Vehicle[]` in place of `registered_vehicles`, hoping to later push multiple vehicles under the `registered_vehicles` array individually. However, passing an empty array was also not possible with the `Vehicle` struct datatype.

When attempting to add data using the function, I receive the following error: `"UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct logistics.Vehicle memory[] memory` to storage not yet supported.

I understand that the issue may be due to multiple dynamic arrays being involved, but I'm unsure of the correct approach. What should I do if I want to add data in this scenario?

```
struct Sensor{
    uint sensor_id;
    string sensor_name;
    string sensor_type;
}

struct Vehicle{
    uint transporter_id;
    string reg_num;
    Sensor[] sensors;
}

struct Participant{
    uint account_id;
    string account_name;
    address account_address;
    Vehicle[] registered_vehicles;
}

mapping(string => Participant[]) ParticipantsData;

function addParticipants(
    string memory role,
    uint account_id,
    string memory account_name,
    address account_address,
    Vehicle[] memory registered_vehicles
    ) public restrictedUsers {

        ParticipantsData[role].push(Participant(account_id, account_name, account_address, registered_vehicles));

        // ParticipantsData[role].push(Participant(account_id, account_name, account_address, Vehicle[]));

        // uint length = ParticipantsData[role].length;
        // ParticipantsData[role][length].account_id = account_id;
        // ParticipantsData[role][length].account_name = account_name;
        // ParticipantsData[role][length].account_address = account_address;

        // for (uint i=0; i < registered_vehicles.length; i++){
        //     ParticipantsData[role][length].registered_vehicles.push(registered_vehicles[i]);
        // }
}
```

Comment: can you add example data, how do you input/send the data (for example using remix)?

Comment: I think first u need to create a Participant in storage without vehicle and push it into mapping. then iterate over the vehicles array, create a vehicle in storage and push it in Participant. After that inside the same loop you need to iterate over sensors, create them and push them into vehicle